# Painted texture not showing up in UV Editor

Tags: texturing, uv

[image: My workplace]I wanted to create and object with texture to export on UE5, for that I needed to export the texture image.
Problem is : I can't save the texture as an image because what I "painted" doesn't show up in the UV Editor. I watched a ton of tutorials but none of them helped me with my problem.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: The UV editor can be set to show any image data block. Use the pull down in the header to select the correct image.

Comment: Hello and welcome, please add images of your uv editor, texture editor, shaders and so, the more, the better to illustrate the issue

Comment: Thank you ! I added the image on the original post for better visibility :)

Comment: hello, please pack your images (File > External Data > Pack All Into .blend) and share your file: https://pasteall.org/blend/

Comment: I can't upload on PasteAll, I put my file into it, i click upload, it loads but then stop and I have nothing

Comment: I ended up finding the solution ! I needed to be in Texture paint and not Vertex paint. Thank you for your intention of helping me, hope you'll all have a great day !